# Excel: Is it possible to converge several ComboBox outputs into a single Cell?

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

**Context**: My Excel worksheet consists of a userform that outputs to several sheets. A function of this userform is a date selector, that is desired to output to a single cell. However, due to the nature of its design (Obtained from a gentleman from this particular site, Doug Glancy) it consists of three comboboxes.

**It is displayed as**:

[ComboBox1: Day] [ComboBox2: Month] [ComboBox3: Year]

[Here is an image for visual reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4Rdn.jpg)

Is there any particular method of forcing a concrescence from several outputs into a single cell? And if not, what would be an alternative method for accomplishing a similar result?

Edit: Here is my current code for transmitting data from the userform:

```
    Sub Transfer()

Dim emptyRow As Long

'Make Sheet2 active
Sheet2.Activate

'Determine emptyRow
emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("B:B")) + 1

'Transfer information
Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = TextBoxSON.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = TextBoxJobDescription.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = TextBoxCustomer.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = TextBoxQuantity.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = TextBoxDateRequired.Value

Dim LR As Integer
LR = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Application.EnableEvents = False
Range("A4:BB" & LR).Sort Key1:=Range("A4"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
    Header:=xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Edit: Big thanks to [CLR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7446760/clr) for the answer:

```
mydate = DateSerial(cboYear.Value, cboMonth.Value, cboDay.Value)
Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = mydate
```

This code enables the data to be output exactly as desired. Hope this helps anyone in the future.

(**Irrelevant (But seemingly necessary) information**: Hey, I'm a new SO user. After hours (and hours) of trying to find and understand this problem, I have not arrived to any possible conclusion and, with the angry hands of the clock pointing furiously at me, I am forced to (shamefully) ask this question.

I am not Excel proficient nor VBA literate. However, I have been slowly learning the language through sites such as HomeandLearn.org to overcome my difficulties but seemingly to no avail on this particular problem. I must apologise in advance for any inappropriate use or misuse of terminology or any other uninformed misapprehension that has been made in my above question. I have attempted to familiarise myself with the community and the rules of this site before asking this question and have searched extensively for an answer.

Any assistance would be appreciated. Thank you.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the cell to contain just the text within the 3 boxes, then use:

```
 mydate = ComboBoxDay.Value & ComboBoxMonth.Value & ComboBoxYear.Value
 Cells(2, 7).Value = mydate
```

However, a more useful approach might be to populate the cell with an actual date:

```
 mydate = DateSerial(ComboBoxYear.Value, ComboBoxMonth.Value, ComboBoxDay.Value)
 Cells(2, 7).Value = mydate
```

Comment: Oddly, the date output is actually different than the date input, for example: 06//03/2017 results in 07/09/2011 being output to the sheet. Any ideas on why this is occurring? Here's the code adapted for the userform: `mydate = DateSerial(cboDay.Value, cboMonth.Value, cboYear.Value) Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = mydate`

Comment: Assuming you're using the 2nd option, check that you're providing the parameters of `DateSerial` in the right order.. i.e. **Year**, **Month** then **Day**?

Comment: Ah, I was simply unaware that the DateSerial function (Thing) had a required format and just assumed that they represented the order in which they were transmitted to the sheet. It now works entirely as desired. I will update the main post to reflect your functioning answer. (PS: Thanks very much!)

Answer (score 0):

This?

```
MyDate = ComboBox1.Value & ComboBox2.Value & ComboBox2.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 7).Value = MyDate
```

Comment: Seemingly, you would appear to be correct. Thank you very much! A single problem remains however: The date is output as a whole, long integer. E.g: 31012017, thus appearing as ####### in the date format. Is there any method of outputing this information with "/" as separators?(Also, I upvoted your comment but due to my account being new it does not display as such) Thanks once again for your assistance.